# mysql how to join with nearest distance

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am using MySQL with PHP , I have a store table and store branches table
,i need to get the stores with the nearest branch name and id

tables

1 - stores

```
|---------------------|------------------| 
|         id          |     name         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     store1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    store 2       |
------------------------------------------
```

2- store_branches

```
    |---------------------|------------|------------------| --------------|-------------|
    |         id          |  store_id  |     name         |   lat         |   lng       |
    |---------------------|------------|------------------|---------------|-------------|
    |          1          |      1     |     branch x     |   30.134166   |  31.384267  |
    |---------------------|------------|------------------|---------------|-------------|
    |          2          |      1     |     branch y     |   31.134168   |  32.384267  |
    |---------------------|------------|------------------|---------------|-------------|
    |          3          |      2     |     branch v     |   34.134140   |  36.384267  |
    |---------------------|------------|------------------|---------------|-------------|
    |          1          |      2     |     branch f     |   36.134181   |  31.384267  |
    |---------------------|------------|------------------| --------------|-------------|
```

what I need to do is to get list of stores with the nears branch from the user

> assume user lat = 30.0736176 & lng = 31.3418702

hears how I tried to do it

```
select `store_branches`.`id` as `branch_id`, `stores`.`id` as `store_id`, `stores`.`name` as `store_name`  
from `stores` 
inner join `store_branches` on stores.id = (
                        SELECT `id` 
                        from `store_branches` 
                        WHERE store_branches.store_id = stores.id
                        order by POW(69.1 * (store_branches.lat - '30.0736176' ), 2) +
                        POW(69.1 * ( '31.3418702' - store_branches.lng) * COS(store_branches.lat / 57.3), 2) asc 
                        limit 1
                     )
 group by `stores`.`id`
```

but it does not work properly

so how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean with "does not work properly"  ?? you have an error  .. show the error message  ..  wrong resutl add  youe expectedc resutl and you actual result

Comment: its no getting an error but it does not get the nearest one, it gets the first one

Answer (score 0):

You should not use group by without aggregation  function in mysql version > 5.6 raise an error for the others versuib  produce unpredictable result  ...  use distinct if you want not duplicated  result

```
    Select DISTINCT `store_branches`.`id` as `branch_id`, `stores`.`id` as `store_id`, `stores`.`name` as `store_name`  
    from `stores` 
    inner join `store_branches` on stores.id = (
                            SELECT `id` 
                            from `store_branches` 
                            WHERE store_branches.store_id = stores.id
                            order by (POW(69.1 * (store_branches.lat - 30.0736176 ), 2) +
                            POW(69.1 * ( 31.3418702 - store_branches.lng) * COS(store_branches.lat / 57.3), 2)) asc 
                            limit 1
                         )
```

and for number you  should not use quotes